# Join Tables not working unless hard code ID

Tags: laravel, join

I forgot I have $weekends id already passed so I did this   public function

```
show(Weekend $weekend) 
    {
        $id = $weekend->id; 
        $teams = DB::table('weekends')
        ->join('weekend_team_members', 'weekend_team_members.weekends_id', '=', 'weekends.id')
        ->select('weekend_team_members.firstname','weekend_team_members.lastname','weekend_team_members.position')
        ->where('weekend_team_members.weekends_id', $id)
        ->get();

        return view('pages.weekend')->with(['weekend' => $weekend,'teams'=> $teams]);
    }
```

This code only works if I change ->where('weekend_team_members.weekends_id', '=','weekends.id') to
->where('weekend_team_members.weekends_id', '=',2) otherwise its an empty array.  I am sure its probably something simple but I can't figure it out.

Here is my join statement

```
 $teams = DB::table('weekends')
    ->join('weekend_team_members', 'weekend_team_members.weekends_id', '=', 'weekends.id')
    ->select('weekend_team_members.firstname','weekend_team_members.lastname','weekend_team_members.position')
    ->where('weekend_team_members.weekends_id', '=','weekends.id')
    ->get();
```

Weekend Model

```
   <?php

namespace App\Models\Webmaster;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Weekend extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $fillable = ['title','verse','songtitle','songvideo','image'];

    public function weekendTeamMembers() {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Models\Webmaster\WeekendTeamMember::class);
    }

 

}
```

WeekendTeamMember Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Webmaster;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class WeekendTeamMember extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['firstname','lastname','position'];

    public function weekend() {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Models\Webmaster\Weekend::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `whereColumn()` method: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses (scroll down a bit). Right now, you're searching against the literal string `weekends.id`:

```
SELECT * FROM `weekends` JOIN ... WHERE `weekend_team_members`.`weekends_id` = 'weekends.id'
```

The `whereColumn()` will ensure you're doing the correct SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `weekends` JOIN ... WHERE `weekend_team_members`.`weekends_id` = `weekends`.`id`
```

Notice the difference between usage of single quotes and backticks:

```
= 'weekends.id'
= `weekends`.`id`
```

One is a string, one is a DB column, and will produce different results.

So, your final query would be:

```php
$teams = DB::table('weekends')
->join('weekend_team_members', 'weekend_team_members.weekends_id', '=', 'weekends.id')
->select('weekend_team_members.firstname','weekend_team_members.lastname','weekend_team_members.position')
->whereColumn('weekend_team_members.weekends_id', 'weekends.id')
->get();
```

(Note: the `=` is implied, it's optional, but `->whereColumn('weekend_team_members.weekends_id', '=', 'weekends.id')` is valid too)

Comment: OK this works but selects all weekends.  I am looking to list all weekend teams that have the weekend_team_members.weekends_id = to weekends.id.  for instance if weekends.id is 1 and there are 4 weekend_team_member.weekends_id with 4 it should only list those 4

Comment: Yeah, the other answer kinda highlights why that's happening. If you never pass some kind of ID, you're just going to get everything, cause your `join()` and `whereColumn()` clauses basically do the same thing. This answer simply highlights the correct syntax to use when trying to compare to a column.

Comment: I saw that answer but not sure what to do to fix it.

Comment: Rethink your approach. Try to figure out the query that works in some kind of SQL editor, then try to translate that to Laravel's query builder. The core issue is not limiting to some kind of `weekends.id` value, so you're getting everything.

Comment: Please don't post that in the comments. Edit your question with that new information; it doesn't format well as a comment.

Comment: Sidenote though, if you have a `Weekend` model, why are you doing `DB::table('weekends')`? Use your model and relationship for this.

Answer (score 0):

First, weekend_team_members.weekends_id isn't going to work natively without defining a column. Laravel expects it to be weekend_id (singular).

Second, your where() clause doesn't accept a column name as an argument and, even if it did, it wouldn't do anything. The "where" you're describing there is already accomplished by your ->join() method (that's what an inner join is).

Third, what is the purpose of the join anyhow? You are only selecting columns from the weekend_team_members table.

If the intention is to filter out weekend_team_members that don't have a weekend_id, then you'd only need to do a ->whereNotNull('weekend_id'). If you wanted to select some columns from the weekends table, you'd be able to do that already from the join you've created.

If you were looking for team members belonging to a *specific* weekend, then you will need to pass it an ID (otherwise how would the query know which weekend you're looking for?).